# how to remove rectangle around checkmark in checkbox (Android)

Tags: android

Is there a way to remove the just the rectangle that surrounds the checkbox in android? I want to keep just the checkmark, not the rectangle.

Comment: Here you go http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-write-custom-checkbox-view.html

Comment: The only way is to make your own checkbox drawable.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use custom check box xml file for this. try the below xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/blue_dark" />
        <gradient  android:endColor="@color/white" android:startColor="@color/blue_dark" android:type="sweep"  />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        <gradient  android:endColor="@color/white" android:startColor="@color/blue_dark" android:type="sweep"  />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/blue_dark" />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

save below image as cbchk_blue and place it drawable folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add transparent background to checkbox in xml

```
<CheckBox
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:button="@drawable/your_checkbox"/>
```